# Access violation when passing pointer to iterator and pointer to list

Tags: list, visual-c++, iterator

I have written a program to merge two sorted lists into a sorted list.  This is in c++.  I have a helper function to load all the remaining elements of the longer list, once the first list is exhausted.  I am passing in a pointer to an iterator and also a pointer to the longer list.  I get the following exception when the function fillToEnd is called.  Why is this happening?

> Unhandled exception at 0x00A37F0C in MergeSortedLists.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.

Here is the code:

```
// Win32Project1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

void fillToEnd(list<int>::const_iterator * anIter, list<int> * aList, list<int> sortedList){

    for (*anIter; *anIter != (*aList).end(); anIter++)
    {
        sortedList.push_back(**anIter);
    }

}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    list<int> x = { 1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 14, 25 };
    list<int> y = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 24, 36, 47 };
    list<int> sortedList;
    bool hasFinished = false;
    list<int>::const_iterator ciX = x.begin();
    list<int>::const_iterator ciX_e = x.end();
    list<int>::const_iterator ciY = y.begin();
    list<int>::const_iterator ciY_e = y.end();
    while (!hasFinished)
    {
        if (*ciX < *ciY)
        {
            sortedList.push_back(*ciX++);
            if (ciX == ciX_e)
            {
                cout << &y;
                fillToEnd(&ciY, &y, sortedList);
                hasFinished = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sortedList.push_back(*ciY++);
            if (ciY == ciY_e)
            {
                fillToEnd(&ciX, &x, sortedList);
                hasFinished = true;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int anInt : sortedList)
    {
        printf("%d,", anInt);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I recommend using references instead of pointers, it's much cleaner that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are incrementing the pointer rather than the iterator.  Deference the pointer first.:

```
void fillToEnd(list<int>::const_iterator * anIter, list<int> * aList, list<int> sortedList){

    for (*anIter; *anIter != (*aList).end(); ++(*anIter))
    {
        sortedList.push_back(**anIter);
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't step into the function so I am assuming the error is happening at the function call...I will check again.